# Can a "program" "engage in research"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

This is regarding a sentence describing a graduate program at a university.

I am pretty sure this is incorrect, but I would like to know why:

> This program engages in research and educates on cutting edge technologies in fields such as ...

EDIT: My principal question has to do with subject/verb usage. Can a "program" "engage in research"? My understanding is that only people or groups of people can engage in research.

Comment: What do you think is incorrect?

Comment: Can a program engage in research? I thought only humans could do that.

Comment: [personification](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personification) or maybe the author implied that those affiliated with the program are doing the actions.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262521/is-there-a-term-for-ascribing-acts-of-the-human-mind-to-non-human-objects-and-w/262524#262524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anthropomorphism in general is acceptable: see [Einstein's use and others](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/262530/130526).

However, anthropomorphism is sometimes used when it would be more accurate to speak of human activity, as in this case. The sentence would be both more accurate and more grammatically correct if rewritten as:

> Participants in this program engage in research and study cutting edge technologies in fields such as ...

Answer (score 0):

Program in your sentence above is referring to a set of classes or courses that define a curriculum or just the curriculum itself. By definition, a list of classes cannot engage.